# DUP directives assembly language allocates space and fill the space with characters

Tags: assembly, x86

I am doing my assembly language assignment and came across some problems.
The question is: Using DUP directive, allocate space for 5 doublewords and 2 bytes in a data segment. then, fill the next 15 spaces with the character&, the 7 spaces that follow with the character% and the space after that with the character capital M.

I have 2 answers for this:

```
.data?
var1 DWORD 5 DUP (?)
var2 BYTE 2 DUP(?)
15 DUP (“&”)
7 DUP (“%”)
1 DUP (“M”)

.data?
var1 DWORD 5 DUP (?)
var2 BYTE 2 DUP(?)
5 DUP (3 DUP(“&”), ("%"))
2 DUP (“%”)
1 DUP (“M”)
```

My questions:

1. Are these correct?
2. When defining data, do I need to care about how many bytes each data type can hold? From textbook, I saw something like this BYTE 4 DUP ("STACK"), and it holds 20 bytes. The question above asked to allocate spaces, what I think is I allocate 5 doubleword = 20 bytes and 2 byte = 2 bytes, in total is 22 bytes, but there are 23 characters to store. Did I understand the question wrongly?

Thank you in advance if you spend your time reading my question.

Comment: Which assembler?

Comment: I'm not sure what the task is asking for, to set up the memory for dwords to the ampersand character/etc (22B + 1B over in total), or (how I read it) to allocate space for dwords+bytes (any content), and then to set up 15+7+1 bytes (space = byte then??) to those characters, so 22 and 23 bytes are not related, but after each other = 45B total? If it's 22+23, then your first definition looks quite ok, I just miss BYTE ahead of the three character lines (but maybe your assembler allows your syntax). Your second variant looks logically wrong to me, producing `&&&%&&&%..` (if that syntax works)?

Comment: *"do I need to care about how many bytes each data type can hold"* - probably not for this task (unless those `'&'` are supposed to set up the dword memory), but generally yes, sure, always be aware of your data structure, and where/how it is stored, generally in IT world data are worth more than a code, usually you can write new code to manipulate old data, if you lose the code, but if you lose the data....